# How can I get the current Umbraco user in a Media.AfterSave event handler?

Tags: c#, umbraco

When I save a Media file in umbraco I get the aftersave event but I don't know how can I get the current user in this context.

Events:
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/overview-of-all-events

I tried, but doesnt work:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/5317-current-login-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just:

```
User currentUser = User.GetCurrent();
```

*(I haven't tested it, though)*

Comment: It looks like this has been deprecated in v 7.x. Use the UserService instead. (message from visual studio) There is a discussion on the trials of using the UserService here - https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/50075-how-to-get-the-current-user-with-UserService -  looks like this answer is still preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If @Douglas Ludlow's solution does not work try this:

```
var userTicket = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).GetUmbracoAuthTicket();
if (userTicket != null)
{
    var currentUser = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.UserService.GetByUsername(userTicket.Name);
}
```